# Play sound for remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to play a sound for remote notifications. the app is registered for remoteNotificatiosTypeSound, the sound is enable in notifications phone settings.

the structure of remote notification is like that in console:

```
{
aps =     {
    alert = "Notification received";
    badge = 1;
    payload = {
        action = A;
        date = "2014-09-16";
        idmessage = 243722;
        message = "";
        time = "11:39:33";
        title = "";
    };
    sound = alarm4.wav;
};
}
```

It is an error somewhere?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
sound = alarm4.wav
```

Does the device have this sound file?
Try

```
"sound": "default"
```

Also, this should be a JSON string so you should have : instead of =

Comment: no, the device doesn't have this sound file (it is just in my project). shoud be one of the device sounds? Thanks

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it and i come back with the result.

Comment: now the sound is one of the phone sound file, but nothing changed

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.
Does the device play a sound now?

Comment: no, any sound played. do you think that sound must to be in payload?

Comment: I think your formatting is incorrect. You should be sending a JSON string, which uses : instead of = and commas(,) instead of ;